# Post/send values to cells in a Excel file and extract result from specific cell?

Tags: php, excel, extract

I have a Excel file stored on my webserver which i use as a calculator. I was wondering if it's any way possible to post/send values to specific cells and then extract the result from a specific cell? I would prefer to do this by PHP.

Comment: Edit: My excel file extension is .xlsm

Comment: why do you want to perform calculation etc in excel file? why not in php? To read excel file in PHP, you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877704/is-there-a-php-library-for-xlsmexcel-with-macro-parsing-editing

Answer (score 0):

Use [phpExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), here's an example to open and modify your existing file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './Classes/');

include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$fileType = 'Excel5'; //you may have to change this value
$fileName = 'yourfile.xlsm';

// Read the file
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

// Change the file
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'World!');

// Write the file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($fileName);
```

---

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation) and list of [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples).